# All forms and buttons mysteriously rendering at 11px font-size

Tags: css, wordpress, debugging

Inspecting my website with dev tools, and on different browsers. The computed `font-size` for all my forms is all over the place:

- Chrome and Safari OS X: `11px`
- FF OS X: `11px` except for some that randomly render at `14px`.
- Opera on Windows: `13px`
- jennyfofenny is even reporting strange font sizes of `13.3333px` on Windows 7 Chrome.

None of these are the standard 14px I've set to `<body>` **or** the 100% browser default of 16. What is going on here?

All of the buttons and inputs are exhibiting this strange behavior: search forms, buttons, my comments section.

I've looked everywhere, tried disabling plugins, tried disabling Javascript, and I simply can't find the source of this bug

[**The Website in question**](http://clusterfoo.com)

### Posible Solution:

Adding the `input` property to the reset sheet starting at `line 30` solves the problem.

#### However:

It's still going to bug me *forever* how this strange behaviour came to be, considering neither `11px` or `13px` are browser defaults for anything AFAIK. (jennyfofenny is even getting strange font sizes of 13.3333 on some browsers!)

Comment: I don't know. But, perhaps by defining font-size: 14px at line 40 of your style.css might work. Is 11px the browser default when font-size set to 100%?

Comment: Default browser font size is 16px.

Comment: Well; again, not an answer but input {
font-size: 14px;
}

Comment: I'd like to add on to orolo's comment about browser defaults. If you don't set a font size, the font size will be set to the browser's default setting. This is the reason many websites will use a reset stylesheet to prevent browser differences in appearance in fonts and spacing (each browser has its own set of default css).

Comment: @jennyfofenny line 40 which orolo refers to is actually part of the reset sheet (which I've borrowed from the skeleton css and is pretty standard, and does reset `form` font to `100%`). Browser default is `16px`, not `11px` or `13px`. I also later define global `<body>` font size at 14. -- `11px` and `13px` seem like such random numbers that they must come from somewhere...

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying now. I don't get 11px for Firefox and Chrome on Windows 7, though. I get 13.3333px and 13px, respectively, which is even weirder. I've been trying to figure out why this is happening, but haven't isolated why this is occurring (since it seems to use the body font-size rule in its calculations).

Comment: @jennyfofenny so something wacky is definitely going on here. at any rate, adding `form` to the reset sheet at line 30 of `style.css` seems to solve the problem. But the mystery is killing me, I must admit, even if the problem itself is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with opanitech. Everything seems to be checking out when I look at your site, and I double checked it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Body copy is showing up as 14px and h1 as 22px. View your site in another browser if possible. You could always add `!important` to your font-sizes just in case.

Comment: It's the strangest thing. Every browser I open is rendering my forms differently. In FF OS X they are all `11px` **except** the actual comment input. In Safari everything is `11px`. Over in my Windows computer, some browsers render forms at `13px`, some `11`. -- This seems like such a strange thing to happen that I won't be happy with  merely forcing it to `14px`; I need to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the font 'profontwindows' that is making your text so small in these elements.

Change that and it definitely gets bigger.

Comment: Computed style is what is changing, not the appearance. It doesn't just look smaller, the browser is actually rendering it at `font-size: 11px`. -- You can see that I use profontwindows throughout my blog and it renders at `14px` as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have multiple CSS files there. for example:

http://public.oneallcdn.com/css/api/socialize/login/frame.css

http://clusterfoo.com/wp-content/themes/Cf/style.css

The 11px font-size is defined in frame.css here:

```
.plugin #providers .provider .name {
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Kalimati, Verdana, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 1px 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: It occured to me: but I deactivate the plugin... and no change. `devtools -> computed style -> font-size` **still** `11px`. I just deactivated the plugin, that stylesheet is no longer showing up... I can't get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you're talking about. https://i.stack.imgur.com/f507r.jpg

Add the WhatFont bookmark to your toolbar and check it out that way.  Make sure your zoom is set to 100% by hitting ctrl+0.  Also make sure you don't have a CSS reset stylesheet included which would change the default font size for all tags.